# How to restore cudnn lstm

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm struggling with restoring the network which was trained with Cudnn Lstm. I'm using Tensorflow 1.12, Cuda 9.0 and Cudnn 7.4. I have trained and saved my network with using,

```
with graph.as_default():
    inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, seq_len, n_channels], name='inputs')
    labels_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name='labels')
    keep_prob_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep')
    learning_rate_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='learning_rate')

    lstm_in = tf.transpose(inputs_, (1, 0, 2))
    cudnn_lstm =tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM(num_layers=2, num_units=36, dtype=tf.float32)  
    outputs_, _ = cudnn_lstm(lstm_in)

with graph.as_default():
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    iteration = 1

    for e in range(epochs):
        for x, y in get_batches(X_tr, y_tr, batch_size):

            feed = {inputs_: x, labels_: y, keep_prob_: 0.5, learning_rate_: learning_rate}

            loss, _,  acc = sess.run([cost, optimizer, accuracy], feed_dict=feed)
  saver.save(sess, "checkpoints/lstm.ckpt")
```

I saved it in a checkpoint file. After that, using the code seen below, I'm trying to restore variables like input placeholder or accuracy.

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('checkpoints/lstm.ckpt.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('checkpoints/.'))  

        input = graph.get_tensor_by_name('inputs:0')
        output = graph.get_tensor_by_name('labels:0')
        pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name('pred_y:0')
        accuracy = graph.get_tensor_by_name('accuracy:0')
        keep_ = graph.get_tensor_by_name('keep:0')
```

But I get this error " The name 'cudnn_lstm/opaque_kernel_saveable' refers to an Operation not in the graph'.
I don't understand anything about opaque parameters here [cudnn_rnn.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/layers/cudnn_rnn.py)

Is there any solution about this problem ?

Error Output:

```
2018-12-24 09:09:32.042319: I 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports 
instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 
FMA
2018-12-24 09:09:32.129542: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful 
NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be 
at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-12-24 09:09:32.130121: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 
with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 
1.7085
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 5.93GiB freeMemory: 4.84GiB
2018-12-24 09:09:32.130135: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible 
gpu devices: 0
2018-12-24 09:09:32.332781: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device 
interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-12-24 09:09:32.332806: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2018-12-24 09:09:32.332813: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2018-12-24 09:09:32.332964: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created 
TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 
4595 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 
6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "restore.py", line 60, in <module>
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('checkpoints/lstm.ckpt.meta')
File "/home/ks/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1674, in 
import_meta_graph
meta_graph_or_file, clear_devices, import_scope, **kwargs)[0]
File "/home/ks/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1696, in 
_import_meta_graph_with_return_elements
**kwargs))
File "/home/ks/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 852, in 
import_scoped_meta_graph_with_return_elements
ops.prepend_name_scope(value, scope_to_prepend_to_names))
File "/home/ks/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3490, in 
as_graph_element
return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, 
allow_operation)
File "/home/ks/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3550, in 
_as_graph_element_locked
"graph." % repr(name))
 KeyError: "The name 'cudnn_lstm/opaque_kernel_saveable' refers to an 
 Operation not in the graph."
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace for your error?

Comment: I added error output. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Could you file a bug? github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new Looks like the CuDNN saveable gets added to a collection, then looked up with an invalid name when it tries to restore the collection (since the saveable saves under a name which isn't a Tensor). We may just want to ignore the error in cases like this.

Comment: Hi Allen, there is a open issue which is very similar to my problem, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23898. Also I added my comment there. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23898#issuecomment-643180325) workaround to fix this issue. Thanks!